# AngularJS Error: error:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs

Trying to bind an array that has duplicates. 
First removing the duplicate with the following. But I get this

```
Error: error:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop

 return myArray.filter(function (elem, pos) {
                       return myArray.indexOf(elem) == pos;
                    });
```

How can remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array every time. If you're using this as part of some binding that uses a regular $watch(the ones that do identity checks, not deep equality ones), then the $watch would produce a "new value" on every $digest, leading to an infinite digest loop.

Instead, you should either only filter it once, or if the data changes, $watch the data, and apply your filter when it does. For example:

```
$scope.$watch('myData', function (value) {
    $scope.myFilteredData = myData.filter(...)
})
// bind to myFilteredData
```

Comment: It's a single field I'm trying to bond.

Comment: myData is  an array of Customer Names. I just want to bind the single field and remove any duplicates. I'm new to Angular. So I need to remove the dups when binding this single field - it would produce a new value everytime